# Tally Integration Using Java

Tags: java-8, odbc, tally

I was trying to Integrate Tally(ERP9 v6.xx) with Java(Java 8) Application.
Ideally,I would need to connect to tally database and should be able to query the available tables.

I have gone through the internet and found,ODBC connection is required for doing this,But I didn't find any samples to query database tables.(Also Java8 doesn't supports ODBC connection).

Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Quite late at seeing this, but if you still need an answer,
Please use Tally XML Integration while working with Java, you can use [Unirest](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/) or Any other convenient HTTP Request Sender.